# CKEditor And PHP, sending to Mysql generates extra tags

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I'm using CKEditor in a PHP webpage and I'm using it to receive a text that will be sent to MySQl for later retrieval, the problem I'm getting is, that when i write something like: "Modificado 3, probando a ver si todo funciona de forma correcta", sorry it's in Spanish, I get something like this inserted into the MYsql database:

```
<p>
    <span data-scayt_word="Modificado" data-scaytid="1">Modificado</span> 3, 
    <span data-scayt_word="probando" data-scaytid="4">probando</span> a 
    <span data-scayt_word="ver" data-scaytid="5">ver</span> 
    <span data-scayt_word="si" data-scaytid="12">si</span> 
    <span data-scayt_word="todo" data-scaytid="13">todo</span> 
    <span data-scayt_word="funciona" data-scaytid="14">funciona</span> de forma correcta
</p>
```

And I don't want anything like that, I wish it would be something like this:

```
<p>Modificado 3, probando a ver si todo funciona de forma correcta</p>
```

I have changed the FullPage config to false and the htmlEncodeOutput to false, any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is down to the API call you're using to get the word data. According to http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8212, you need to use getData( ) instead. 
Although, I've not tested this.

The other thing suggested is to disable the scayt plugin.